# How to choose the shown decimals in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, decimal

I'm trying to write a code which takes some numbers from certain cells and uses their values in sentences. However the decimal points are too much and I could not narrow them down

```
Dim export As Long

Select Case export
    Case Is >= 1000000000
        result = "Dünya … ihracatı incelenmiştir. 2018 yılı dünya ihracat değeri yaklaşık " & Range("G15").Value / 1000000000 & " milyar $'dır."
    Case Is >= 1000000
        result = "Dünya … ihracatı incelenmiştir. 2018 yılı dünya ihracat değeri yaklaşık " & Range("G15").Value / 1000000 & " milyon $'dır."
    Case Is >= 1000
        result = "Dünya … ihracatı incelenmiştir. 2018 yılı dünya ihracat değeri yaklaşık " & Range("G15").Value / 1000 & " bin $'dır."
End Select

Range("O2").Value = result
```

For instance the value in G15 is  1.724.372 right now. And the result I'm getting is:

Dünya … ihracatı incelenmiştir. 2018 yılı dünya ihracat değeri yaklaşık 1,724372 milyon $'dır.

I just want the 1,7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Round (Range("G15").Value / 1000000, 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using as @CLR stated `Round(Range("G15").Value / 1000000, 1)`. To expand on that a little bit though you could use the following

```
Const StartString As String = "Dünya … ihracati incelenmistir. 2018 yili dünya ihracat degeri yaklasik "
Const EndString As String = " $'dir."
Dim result As String
Dim strEndings() As Variant: strEndings = Array(" bin", " milyon", " milyar")
Dim RoundedNumber As Double
Dim t As Double
Dim i As Long

t = Range("G15").Value2

For i = 9 To 3 Step -3
    RoundedNumber = t / (1 * 10 ^ i)
    If RoundedNumber > 1 Then Exit For
Next i
If i > 0 Then
    result = Round(RoundedNumber, 1) & strEndings((i / 3) - 1)
Else
    result = t
End If

Range("O2").Value2 = StartString & result & EndString
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Round` function:

```
Dim export As Long

Select Case export
    Case Is >= 1000000000
        result = "Dünya … ihracati incelenmistir. 2018 yili dünya ihracat degeri yaklasik " & Round(Range("G15").Value / 1000000000, 1) & " milyar $'dir."
    Case Is >= 1000000
        result = "Dünya … ihracati incelenmistir. 2018 yili dünya ihracat degeri yaklasik " & Round(Range("G15").Value / 1000000, 1) & " milyon $'dir."
    Case Is >= 1000
        result = "Dünya … ihracati incelenmistir. 2018 yili dünya ihracat degeri yaklasik " & Round(Range("G15").Value / 1000, 1) & " bin $'dir."
End Select

Range("O2").Value = result
```

Where `Round(1.2345678, 1)` would equal `1.2`